# Errors on the request (forbidden + empty string)

Tags: ajax, magento

I am new to magento and not so expierenced with ajax. I need to do a ajax request to send the data to the php. I have this code to send the data to the php file:

```
function Ajax() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "./handler.php",
        data: {
            source1: catId
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

It seems that the data won't reach the php file. If anyone can help me fix my code, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JS, so you need the full URL for an ajax request.

```
url: "http://www.test.com/handler.php",
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was i didnt put it in the right folder... found it thanks to you